# pass output from controller to view

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Belove is my code , I am trying to pass output from controller to view, Now My Problem is that when I do code this `$errormsg =  $this->_setError('f_001'); $this->_view->set('errormsg', $errormsg);`it workes in index() but not in processjobsearch().

processjobsearch()function I am calling through ajax ,how can i set output to view now , where I am going wrong ? Pls can anyone help me out ..

**calling function in jobs/index.tpl **

```
    function jobsearch()
    {
         var form=$("#jobSearchForm")   
           //$("#result").html("<img alt="ajax search" src='ajax-loader.gif'/>"); 
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/jobs/processjobsearch/',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                alert(data);  
                //document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = data; 
                            $.each(data, function(index, value) { alert(value);
                                     $.each(value, function(index, value) { 
                                      $("#data").append("<tr><td>" + value + '</td></tr>');
                                });   
                             });         
                            }       
            }); 
    }
//accessing value like this

<?php echo $errormsg; ?> //this gives me output if called from index() 
           //but doesn't give output when called from processjobsearch()
```

**global view**

```
class View
{
    protected $_file;
    protected $_data = array();

    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->_file = $file;
    }
   public function assign($variable , $value)
        {
        $this->data[$variable] = $value;
        }
    public function set($key, $value)
    { 
        $this->_data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
      return $this->_data[$key];
    }

    public function output()
    {
        if (!file_exists($this->_file))
        {
            throw new Exception("View " . $this->_file . " doesn't exist.");
        }

        extract($this->_data);
        ob_start();
        include($this->_file);
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

**global controller**

```
 class Controller
    {
        protected $_model;
        protected $_controller;
        protected $_action;
        protected $_view;
        protected $_modelBaseName;  
        protected $cookName;
        //protected $_data = array();

        public function __construct($model, $action)
        { 
            $this->_controller = ucwords(__CLASS__);
            $this->_action = $action;
            $this->_modelBaseName = $model;

            $this->_view = new View('views' . DS . strtolower($this->_modelBaseName) . DS . $action . '.tpl');
        }

        protected function _setModel($modelName)
        {
            $modelName .= 'Model';
            $this->_model = new $modelName();
        }

        protected function _setView($viewName)
        {
            $this->_view = new View('views' . DS . strtolower($this->_modelBaseName) . DS . $viewName . '.tpl');
        }
        public function _setError($errorCode)
        {  //echo "pass1";
         $errormsg = $this->_model->getError($errorCode); //echo $errormsg [jserr_msg]; 
         return $errormsg [jserr_msg];  
        }
}
```

**jobscontroller**

```
class JobsController extends Controller
 {
    public function __construct($model, $action)
    {
        parent::__construct($model, $action);
        $this->_setModel($model);
    }     
    public function index()
    {  
        $this->_view->set('title', 'Job Search');           
       $script2 = BASE_FRONT.'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js';     
        $script4 = BASE_FRONT.'js/scw.js';      
        $js_global = array( $script2, $script4);
       $this->_view->set('js_global', $js_global);
     $errormsg =  $this->_setError('f_001'); 
      $this->_view->set('errormsg', $errormsg);    //in index function it works  
        return $this->_view->output();
    }
    /**
    * Defines processjobsearch, called from jobs/index.tpl file
    * it process value to search getJobSearchData function in jobsinmodel to get relative detail.
    */
    public function processjobsearch()
{ 
try {   
    $valToSearch = isset($_POST['keyword']) ? trim($_POST['keyword']) : NULL;
        $nature = isset($_POST['nature']) ? trim($_POST['nature']) : NULL;
        $jobs = $this->_model->getJobSearchData($valToSearch, $nature);    
      // print_r($jobs);
    $errormsg =  $this->_setError('f_001'); 
    $this->_view->set('errormsg', $errormsg); //here it doesn't works
    $this->_view->set('jobs', $jobs);   
    // return $this->_view->output();   
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '<h1>Application error:</h1>' . $e->getMessage();
    }       
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_setError()` method is not defined in `Controller` or `JobsController`. It shouldn't work in either the `index()` or `processjobsearch()` methods.

I assume you want to do something like this (although I'm not sure why):

```php
class Controller {
    //...

    protected function _setError($errorCode) {
        //do something with code to produce a message??
        return $errorMsg;
    }
}
```

Edit:

Ah okay, I see what you're doing now. The variable `$errormsg` in `jobs/index.tpl` is fulfilled by your `View::output()` method. Obviously JS (being client side) cannot update this PHP variable, so you need to grab the value via AJAX and populate the HTML element containing this value.

I can see that your JS code is trying to populate a table cell with with the result of `processjobsearch()` (via AJAX), however nothing is actually returned from this method. You're adding data to your view, but not outputting it.

Perhaps, rather than a `jobs/processjobsearch.tpl`, you could use a `jobs/processjobsearch.json` and populate it with your view data. You could then grab this data via ajax and use JS to change the error message.

Something like this:

```js
function jobsearch()
{
    var form=$("#jobSearchForm")
    //$("#result").html("<img alt="ajax search" src='ajax-loader.gif'/>");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/jobs/processjobsearch/',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);

            $.each(json.jobs, function(index, value) { alert(value);
                $.each(value, function(index, value) {
                    $("#data").append("<tr><td>" + value + '</td></tr>');
                });
            });

            $('#errorr-msg').html(json.errormsg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question i have forgot to add that function in question but it does exist der

Comment: `/processjobsearch.tpl` is not file it is an function so how can I change it to `/processjobsearch.json`, and I tried your code it is giving me this error `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: I am aware `processjobsearch.tpl` doesn't actually exist yet, but I assumed a basic naming convention. That is, if `JobController::index()` has the template `jobs/index.tpl`, the template for  `JobController::processjobsearch()` would be `jobs/processjobsearch.tpl`. I'm suggesting that as the `processjobsearch()`method is called via AJAX, the result should be JSON. You can then separate out the jobs data and error data with JS. The above code is not supposed to just work, but to get you on the right track.